# 2GP Unlocked package show CustomTab on install?

Tags: metadata-api, 2gp

I have a 2GP Unlocked package that contains a CustomTab. The end goal is to have a managed 2GP, but I'm not there yet.

After the installation of the package, if the user want to see the tab in the Sales App, he has to click on "Personalize your nav bar", select the tab in the Navigation Items list by clicking "Add More Items".

I'd like that the new tab is displayed by default after installing the package, but I'm not sure it's possible...

How can I do this?

Comment: BTW, unlocked packages and managed packages have some significant behavioural differences to be aware of when performing upgrades. Various things, like page layouts, picklists and apps, do not upgrade after first install for a managed package, but do for an unlocked one. Do not get used to the latter's behaviour and expect to see the same with a managed package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Typically, vendors will create their own custom app and include it in the package. This way, users can switch to your app and use the tabs in the way that you intended.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I thought, but I was not 100% sure.